# How do I alter the title snippet for my site in the Google search results to use a dash rather than a colon after my brand name?

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search

This is how my site is displayed now: **East Main & Co.: Official Site**

This is how I want my site to display: **East Main & Co. – Official Site**

How do I alter the appearance of the main link displayed, changing it from `:` to `–`

For clarification, the link I'm referring to is the first one displayed upon doing a Google search for "east main & co"

Comment: Does that really matter? Is any change worth making when you already rank first? Is it worth the risk?

Comment: Hi @JohnConde, valid point. I had not considered this.
I'm glad I joined this site, very helpful members.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Google [will alter your content](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/35264), as they see fit, to provide users with what they want (that is, what Google thinks they want).

When I googled that query I saw the exact snippet you described but it doesn't match what I see when I 'view source': `Official Site &ndash; East Main &amp; Co.`

I don't mean to be rude but your site/brand doesn't seem like it has enough clout to worry about impostors so "Official Site" seems like a waste of valuable title space.

"east main & co" is a branded query (it's not a search for "official site") so why wouldn't Google customize the snippet to match the search intent?

If I were writing a title for your home page (without having done any keyword/competitive research), I'd write something like `East Main & Co: Men's Clothing, Activewear & Hats`

Comment: Hey adam-asdf, wonderful insight. I can't argue with flawless logic.

Comment: @NewGuyHere Welcome to the site and the complexities of trying to rank in Google.